# Android apk build using button

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am new to Android development and I'm trying to like kind of backup the app or it will produce apk using button.

Example I have a Activity called backup and a button, is it possible that after clicking the button it will generate an Apk via codes? So it can be used as backup. I already did some like kind of search of samples about that but unfortunately I found nothing so maybe I will ask if it is possible then if possible can i ask some guides? Any answers would be so much appreciated.